# Send a json value to another method of my play application

Tags: json, scala, http, playframework

I'm writing a Play 2.3.2 application in Scala.
In my application I have the `Application` object, in that object I have the `advise` methodthat get some data in Json format and returns a Json response.

Now I'm writing an other object that get some data in Json and call the `advise` method passing a Json data, how can i make that in Play??

I've search on the web but I don't have find nothing.

@edit

```
object Application extends Controller {

  /**
   *
   */
  def advise = CorsAction.async { request =>

    implicit val userRestFormat = UserFormatters.restFormatter
    implicit val inputFormat = InputFormatters.restFormatter
    implicit val outputWriter = OutputFormatters.restWriter

    def elaborate(json: JsValue) = {//some work, return an Ok(json) response
    }


    request.body match {
      case AnyContentAsJson(json) => elaborate(json)
      case AnyContentAsText(text) => elaborate(Json.parse(text))
      case AnyContentAsRaw(raw) => {
        raw.asBytes() match {
          case Some(bytes) => elaborate(Json.parse(new String(bytes)))
          case None => Future { Ok(Json.obj("Error" -> "no-body")) }
        }
      }
      case other => Future { Ok(Json.obj("Error" -> "Expected a application/json")) }
    }
  }
}
```

My project is a module is used by another Java play application.

The problem is that this method returns a json, but in some case the java application don't need a json response, but an Ok response is sufficient.

So the method that I'm writing had the following prototype:

```
   def addTagToUser = CorsAction.async { request =>
       def elaborate(json: JsValue): Future[Result] ={
           //here I want to send an http request to the advise method and send the json to that.
       }

 val jsonData = request.body.asJson //get the json data
     jsonData match {
       case Some(x) => val user = x \ "user"; val tag = x \ "tag";
                    (user \ "id", user \ "email", tag \ "category", tag \ "attr") match {
                      case (userId: JsString, userEmail: JsString,
                          tagCat: JsString, tagAtr: JsString) => val myUser = new User(userId.as[String], Some(userEmail.as[String]))
                                                                 val newTag = new Tag(tagCat.as[String], tagAtr.as[String])
                                                                 updateTagToUserDB(myUser, newTag).flatMap(status => status match {
                                                                   case true => Future{Ok}//the update was executed correctly
                                                                   case false => Future{InternalServerError("Cannot access to the db now")}//update fail
                                                                 }
                                                                   )
                      case _ => Future{BadRequest("json bad formed")} // the json is bad formed

                    }

       case None => Future{BadRequest("need a json value")}

     }
   }
```

Comment: It would be easier to answer you if you'd provided some code or, at least, the signature of your methods. BTW, is your json a raw string or is it already a Json object from the play api ?

Comment: So I suppose, `advise` is an `Action`. If that's the case, just extract the statements and calls from advise and put them in a specific method that you can call from wherever you want.

Comment: I've post my code on my question, see my @edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you absolutely expect the communication to be done via HTTP, you will need to use the play's webservice to do so. Have a look to the documentation of WS : https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.4/ScalaWS

If you have an explicit dependency from one project to the other, it may be simpler just to extract the method that transforms the json and then just to build an Ok with that…

Answer (score 0):

Make an "internal" method and call it in whatever way you like from anywhere you like; don't use JSON for internal communication unless you're calling between two different servers/services. You can then either call that method from your code and get a statically typed return value, or map the method to a URL with wrapping code that marshals between JSON and your internal data types.